# Why does my bootstrap dropdown not work?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4, razorengine

```
<div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default orange-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Mora actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
     <ul class="dropdown-menu list ">
       <li><a href="@Url.Action("LiveDetails", "Live", new {id})">Details</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Fetch</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Delay</a></li>
      <li><a href="">Stop</a></li>
      <li><a href="">start</a></li>
     </ul>
</div>
```

I tried to use Asp.net mvc syntax to navigate to another action of the same controller but it doesn't do so, and even when i try to inspect in browser to see there is any  a-tag with a full link like href="Live/Liveservices/id" but nothing shown

Comment: Are you sure you are linking all the required files properly? If i put the code into a standard bootstrap template it works like it should.

Comment: i use visual studio  IDE and nothind displays

Comment: No errors or anything? Just a white screen? Give us your full code please.

Comment: no error just <a>Details</a> but  i put  @Url.Action("LiveServices")

Comment: `new {id}` makes no sense - it would need to be `new { id = someValue }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fully working Dropdown menu with bootstrap

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
    More
    <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action("LiveDetails", "Live", new {id})">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fetch</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Delay</a></li>
  <li><a href="">Stop</a></li>
  <li><a href="">start</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Make sur that you added Jquery script before Bootstrap script

Here is a link in codepen https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JpdJoq

Comment: the problem is  this  <a href="@Url.Action("Liveservices")">Details</a> doesn't even processed

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems working. Did you add necessary scripts to your program?

Check whether you have added jquery, bootstrap.min.js and bootstrap.min.css files. And check for bootstrap versions are correctly added.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default orange-btn dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">
           Mora actions
        <span class="caret"></span>
        </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu list ">
    <li><a href="@Url.Action(" LiveDetails ", "Live ", new {id})">Details</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Fetch</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Delay</a></li>
    <li><a href="">Stop</a></li>
    <li><a href="">start</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrapbundle")

Comment: is it working now? because in the snippet code works